# Question on chrome's user-data-dir and profile-directory

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome has a user data directory (command line --user-data-dir, defaulting to a "User data" directory) and multiple profile directories (command line --profile-directory, defaulting to "Profile 1" and then sequentially incrementing)

My question is, when would I want to create a new user-data-dir, and when would I want to create profile-dirs within a given user-data-dir?

The advantage I see in having a multiple profiles is I can right click a link and say "open in another profile". Additionally, going to menu and clicking on "exit" closes every window in every profile within that user-data-dir

The disadvantage, when my chrome freezes/hangs, it takes all the windows of all the profiles currently open within that user-data-dir. Additionally, all the directories other than "Default" and "Profile-*" take up only 94mb.

So what is the use case envisioned by the developers? When would it be better to use user-data-dir and when profile dirs?